# Why can't PHP's PDO ext automatically escape input?

Tags: php, pdo

Instead of having to bind every value in a separate statement, why can't PHP PDO have some config setting to just escape all input?

Comment: lol thx for the downvotes guys, appreciate it.  But if you're going to downvote, at least leave a comment.

Comment: You can have another -1 for complaining about downvotes and using txtspeak at that. And it doesn't really read like a technical question, but more like grouching. As for an explanation: when you intermingle data values into SQL commands, then the PHP runtime will concatenate the string. The PDO API has no chance to see which parts originated from variables or constants, and magic SQL safemaking for lazyness is not implementable.

Comment: +1 for explanation, -1 for describing my sentence as txtspeak just because I used lol and thx.  I guess we should also refrain from using variables names like PDO either, since no one likes to save time or anything.  I really don't see why ppl need to be so snobby about questions like these.  The only thing I complained about was downvotes without comments.  Not everyone has a degree in comp sci.  On the bright side, I do appreciate the actual answer portion of your response and found it to be very helpful.

Answer (score 4):

If you're binding everything individually, you're doing things the hard way. Don't.

```
$dbh = PDO->new(...);
$sth = $dbh->prepare("SELECT foo FROM bar WHERE baz = ?");
$sth->execute(array("this doesn't need to be escaped!"));
...
```

You can make this even easier with a wrapper function:

```
function dbQuery($sql /* ... */) {
    global $dbh;
    $args = func_get_args();
    array_shift($args);
    $sth = $dbh->prepare($sql);
    $sth->execute($args);
    return $sth;
 }

 $sth = dbQuery("SELECT foo FROM bar WHERE baz = ? AND qux != ?", "blah", "blah blah");
 ...
```

Comment: Duskwuff, thx for replying.  The reason I have to bind everything individually is that it is for a search function, which allows for many different fields, and i'm not sure we fields will be filled out.